# Podman build command unable to pull image

Tags: rhel7, podman

I have configured Subuid and Subgid after installing Podman in RHEL7

I have created a simple Dockerfile to print hello world and was trying to build the image.
My Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
CMD ["echo", "Hello World"]
```

To test I am running below command

```
Podman build -t imagename .
```

I see the below error received.

```
STEP 1: FROM alpine
Error: error creating build container: The following failures happened while trying to pull image specified by "alpine" based on search registries in /etc/containers/registries.conf:
* "localhost/alpine": Error initializing source docker://localhost/alpine:latest: error pinging docker registry localhost: Get https://localhost/v2/: dial tcp [::1]:443: connect: connection refused
* "registry.access.redhat.com/alpine": Error initializing source docker://registry.access.redhat.com/alpine:latest: error pinging docker registry registry.access.redhat.com: Get https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/: read tcp 10.70.85.174:17758->23.54.147.129:443: read: connection reset by peer
* "registry.redhat.io/alpine": Error initializing source docker://registry.redhat.io/alpine:latest: error pinging docker registry registry.redhat.io: Get https://registry.redhat.io/v2/: read tcp 10.70.85.174:36028->104.79.150.216:443: read: connection reset by peer
* "docker.io/library/alpine": Error initializing source docker://alpine:latest: error pinging docker registry registry-1.docker.io: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: read tcp 10.70.85.174:53352->18.213.137.78:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

Am I missing any configuration ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you still the docket Daemon running and/or docker installed?

First stop the docker Daemon

```
 sudo systemctl stop docker
```

OR

```
 sudo service docker stop
```

Then uninstall docker
Ubuntu here but what ever you need you can Google :D

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

Try again,

If other fail now try a refreshed install of podman

```
sudo --reinstall install podman
```

Sources

```
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-reinstall-a-package-using-apt-get-command/
https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker
https://intellipaat.com/community/43965/how-to-stop-docker
https://podman.io/getting-started/installation
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but what is the need to stop docker and uninstall it ? Cant we have Podman also when Docker is running ?

Comment: It is perfectly possible to use and have docker plus postman side by side. Kinda no need though as podman has more to it and is safer. The images, although docker and podman can use the same images, they do store them in different places and can get a tad confusing. Having the docker daemon running us the main culprit.

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/02/21/podman-and-buildah-for-docker-users/

Comment: Ok Bob, I will try your suggestion and let you know

Comment: I have uninstalled Docker and reinstalled Podman, Now I face a new err  podman build -t podmanimg1 .
STEP 1: FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/rhel
Getting image source signatures
....
Storing signatures
Error: error creating build container: Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256:b8e505a039d6d08bfb73": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): there might not be enough IDs available in the namespace (requested 192:192 for /run/systemd/netif): lchown /run/systemd/netif: invalid argument

Comment: I did configure Subuid and Subgid

Comment: Hi Bob, I see that this issue occurs only for LDAP users. We tried in a non LDAP user LINUX VM and see Podman works perfectly.   The issue is with LDAP linked accounts.  Do you have any idea if we can have Podman for LDAP users

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you first search your image in registries

```
podman search alpine
```

you should get a list of images available. Choose the one you want - version, name, tag etc and put that in the dockerfile.

to be sure it is accessible, do the 'pull' manually

```
podman pull alpine<version,tag>
```

Comment: I tried what you have said, it give me more error  ERRO[0001] error searching registry "registry.access.redhat.com": couldn't search registry "registry.access.redhat.com": error pinging docker registry registry.access.redhat.com: Get https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/: read tcp 10.xxx:32528->xxx:443: read: connection reset by peer,  error searching registry "docker.io": couldn't search registry "docker.io": error pinging docker registry index.docker.io: Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: read tcp x.x.x.:51053->3x.x.x.:443: read: error pinging docker registry

Comment: Should I be configuring any localhost registry by updating registries conf ?

Comment: ok, then you really have an issue with connecting to the registry. on some systems the registries configuration is in '/etc/containers/registries.conf' . On what system are you? VM from Red Hat? If you are not administrating the system, I would advise you to contact the administrator and relate the problem.